# SqlCeException database is opened with a read-only connection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, sql-server-ce

We store a template for building SQL Server CE connection strings in our `web.config` and use `string.format` to set the data source and temp path values.

In the `web.config`, the template for the DB connection string is:

```
"Data Source={0}; Temp Path={1}; Mode=Read Only"
```

In the `web.release.config`, we use to build deployment packages, the template for the DB connection string is:

```
Data Source={0}; Temp Path={1}
```

Now we only use the SQL Server CE database for read only operations. So, being a smartypants, I thought I would remove the connection string transform in the `web.release.config` and just always use the read only connection string from the `web.config`.

This worked fine for the database I was testing. But the same code running with a different SQL Server CE database fails with the following exception:

> Exception 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' with message 'The
>   database is opened with a read-only connection. Can't perform
>   post-initialization operations like re-building indexes and upgrading
>   public tracking. Please re-open with a read-write connection. [
>   Database name = D:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\App_Data\Storage.sdf ]'

We are using the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0` provider

Why in my release build that is deployed to a server does read only access fail for some SQL Server CE databases but not others? It is the same code, just pointing at a different `.SDF` file. The `.SDF` files have the same schema, just different data.

Is the driver trying to rebuild indexes because the `.SDF` file is in some older format? Should we never use a readonly connection in production? Is that why the original code had the transform? why do they all work with a readonly connection on my Windows 7 workstation?

Answer (score 2):

You should always specify a temp path, as moving databases between OS platforms/versions can require index rebuilds.

See my blog post post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2009/08/running-sql-compact-from-cd-rom-read.html for more detailed info.

Comment: Temp Path was specified in both configurations. The difference is the  Mode=Read Only was set in one config and not the other.